# How To Add Custom Meta PDF Upload Box to WooCommerce Products (and post link on frontend)

Tags: metabox, woocommerce-offtopic

I have attempted the following a few different ways. The current way I have the functionality works fine but does NOT utilize the WP Media Uploader (which makes finding 1600+ PDF files on the site to upload cumbersome). I recently found the below snippet of code and tweaked it to work for WooCommerce products.

The only issue is that I can't seem to figure out what to call to have the URL of the PDF that's uploaded with the meta box presented on the frontend as a link (i.e. Click Here to Download Product Tearsheet).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
/* PDF Tear Sheet on Product Pages */

//Add Metabox
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_upload_file_metaboxes');

function add_upload_file_metaboxes() {
add_meta_box('swp_file_upload', 'File Upload', 'swp_file_upload', 'product', 'normal', 'default');
}


function swp_file_upload() {
global $post;
// Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
echo '<input type="hidden" name="tearsheetmeta_noncename" id="tearsheetmeta_noncename" value="'.
wp_create_nonce(plugin_basename(__FILE__)).
'" />';
global $wpdb;
$strFile = get_post_meta($post -> ID, $key = 'tearsheet_file', true);
$media_file = get_post_meta($post -> ID, $key = '_wp_attached_file', true);
if (!empty($media_file)) {
    $strFile = $media_file;
} ?>


<script type = "text/javascript">

    // Uploading files
    var file_frame;
jQuery('#upload_image_button').live('click', function(product) {

    podcast.preventDefault();

    // If the media frame already exists, reopen it.
    if (file_frame) {
        file_frame.open();
        return;
    }

    // Create the media frame.
    file_frame = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
        title: jQuery(this).data('uploader_title'),
        button: {
            text: jQuery(this).data('uploader_button_text'),
        },
        multiple: false // Set to true to allow multiple files to be selected
    });

    // When a file is selected, run a callback.
    file_frame.on('select', function(){
        // We set multiple to false so only get one image from the uploader
        attachment = file_frame.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();

        // here are some of the variables you could use for the attachment;
        //var all = JSON.stringify( attachment );
        //var id = attachment.id;
        //var title = attachment.title;
        //var filename = attachment.filename;
        var url = attachment.url;
        //var link = attachment.link;
        //var alt = attachment.alt;
        //var author = attachment.author;
        //var description = attachment.description;
        //var caption = attachment.caption;
        //var name = attachment.name;
        //var status = attachment.status;
        //var uploadedTo = attachment.uploadedTo;
        //var date = attachment.date;
        //var modified = attachment.modified;
        //var type = attachment.type;
        //var subtype = attachment.subtype;
        //var icon = attachment.icon;
        //var dateFormatted = attachment.dateFormatted;
        //var editLink = attachment.editLink;
        //var fileLength = attachment.fileLength;

        var field = document.getElementById("tearsheet_file");

        field.value = url; //set which variable you want the field to have
    });

    // Finally, open the modal
    file_frame.open();
});

</script>



<div>

    <table>
    <tr valign = "top">
    <td>
    <input type = "text"
name = "tearsheet_file"
id = "tearsheet_file"
size = "70"
value = "<?php echo $strFile; ?>" />
    <input id = "upload_image_button"
type = "button"
value = "Upload">
    </td> </tr> </table> <input type = "hidden"
name = "img_txt_id"
id = "img_txt_id"
value = "" />
    </div>     <?php
function admin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
}

function admin_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}
add_action('admin_print_scripts', 'admin_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_styles', 'admin_styles');
}


//Saving the file
function save_tearsheet_meta($post_id, $post) {
// verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
// because save_post can be triggered at other times
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['tearsheetmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
    return $post -> ID;
}
// Is the user allowed to edit the post?
if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post -> ID))
    return $post -> ID;
// We need to find and save the data
// We'll put it into an array to make it easier to loop though.
$tearsheet_meta['tearsheet_file'] = $_POST['tearsheet_file'];
// Add values of $tearsheet_meta as custom fields

foreach($tearsheet_meta as $key => $value) {
    if ($post -> post_type == 'revision') return;
    $value = implode(',', (array) $value);
    if (get_post_meta($post -> ID, $key, FALSE)) { // If the custom field already has a value it will update
        update_post_meta($post -> ID, $key, $value);
    } else { // If the custom field doesn't have a value it will add
        add_post_meta($post -> ID, $key, $value);
    }
    if (!$value) delete_post_meta($post -> ID, $key); // Delete if blank value
    }
 }
add_action('save_post', 'save_tearsheet_meta', 1, 2); // save the custom fields
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey all (especially @Innate), I was able to sort it out ages ago but clearly forgot to come back here and share how I did it. I ended up nixing the idea of using the Media Uploader (due to it being hit-or-miss with larger PDF uploads) and instead just used the text field. I gave the client FTP access under a specific sub-folder (in this case: "tearsheets") and instructed them how to copy and paste the URL to the PDFs they upload. Then I just added the snippet (see below) to the correct single product templates for WooCommerce for it to show on the frontend.

Thanks again for trying to help!

`<a href="<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_nlttearsheet', true ); ?>">Download Tear Sheet</a>`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is with a plugin. I use ACF ([Advanced Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)) to create the meta box which takes care of all the heavy lifting and displays a nice metabox on the edit product screen. I then add a function on my single product template to display the PDF link which can be done using a function or within the template itself where required. Using some conditional logic, the PDF link only displays when there is one :-)

Here is a snippet for the custom field:

```
$pdf_media_file = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'pdf_media_file', true);

if(isset($pdf_media_file) && !empty($pdf_media_file)){
    $pdf_file = wp_get_attachment_url($pdf_media_file);     
}
```

You can then display the link to the file like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $pdf_file; ?>">View the PDF</a>
```

WordPress has a PDF image generator now so you can also have fun using the PDF thumbnail in the media library.

Comment: can you show the function code

Comment: see my edits @owaishanif786 - assuming you use the field 'pdf_media_file' in ACF and return the ID which is a setting on this field type in ACF.

Comment: Downvoted as it is just not smart to install a bloated plugin just for one small functionality. Anyway,it is not clear from the answer how to configure ACF to have that code work, which is not the fault of the answer, but the fault of how complex ACF is.